# jQuery each loop in table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, each, tablerow

I am having something like:

```
<table id="tblOne">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id="tblTwo">
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Items
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Prod
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Item 1
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Item 2
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I have written jQuery to loop through each tr like:

```
$('#tblOne tr').each(function() {...code...});
```

But problem is that it loops through the "tr" of "tblTwo" also which I don't want.
Can anyone please suggest something to solve this?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

In jQuery just use:

```
$('#tblOne > tbody  > tr').each(function() {...code...});
```

Using the children selector (`>`) you will walk over all the children (and not *all* descendents), example with three rows:

```
$('table > tbody  > tr').each(function(index, tr) { 
   console.log(index);
   console.log(tr);
});
```

Result:

```
0
<tr>
1 
<tr>
2
<tr>
```

---

In *VanillaJS* you can use `document.querySelectorAll()` and walk over the rows using `forEach()`

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#tblOne > tbody  > tr'), function(index, tr) {
    /* console.log(index); */
    /* console.log(tr); */
});
```

Comment: @Raynos please explain instead of "hit-and-running"...

Comment: How do I refer to the tr element within the function?

Comment: @Rubiksmomo - use function(index, element) - https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 75):

Just a recommendation:

I'd recommend using the DOM table implementation, it's very straight forward and easy to use, you really don't need jQuery for this task.

```
var table = document.getElementById('tblOne');

var rowLength = table.rows.length;

for(var i=0; i<rowLength; i+=1){
  var row = table.rows[i];

  //your code goes here, looping over every row.
  //cells are accessed as easy

  var cellLength = row.cells.length;
  for(var y=0; y<cellLength; y+=1){
    var cell = row.cells[y];

    //do something with every cell here
  }
}
```

Comment: I agree that jQuery is often not really necessary for this kind of task (especially on newer browser with `.querySelectorAll()`) but if you're already including jQuery it's a waste not to use it (and DOM solution with two `for` loop is not so straightforward, imho)

Comment: But if you're already including jQuery then your doing it wrong and need to remove it ASAP

Comment: ***using*** jQuery also has consequences. $() does about 100 things before it actually selects your element by it's id (as an example) . I'm not saying don't use it... but for trivial things like this where the vanilla js solution is like a few characters more to write you're saving on processing. albeit not much... but why do 10 000/second when you can do 10 000 000.... just makes sense no?

Comment: @F.Calderan I understand what you mean, but like i said, it's a recommendation, because it's very straigth forward. something like accidentaly selecting more tables won't happen here and the iteration with a for-loop is pretty fast.

Comment: @GNi33 it would be faster if you use `document.querySelectorAll(''#tblOne > tbody  > tr')` instead :) - @riemon I suppose jQuery has some internal optimizations so in newer browser it calls native methods like that

Comment: @F.Calderan your joking / trolling / ignorant right? QSA is slow as hell, jQuery optimizes as hard as it can, it's still an order of magnitude slower then the DOM.

Comment: Faster to write, maybe. Faster to run? You have to be kidding.

Comment: @Raynos sorry probably I'm misunderstanding what you're saying.

Comment: @F.Calderan your implying `document.querySelectorAll('#tblOne > tbody > tr')` is faster then `document.getElementById("tblOne").rows` which is simply stupid.

Comment: no, sorry I mean it's faster [but only to write]. It's obvious that second statement will be faster (as execution speed). just a misunderstanding :)

Comment: @F.Calderan What do you mean faster to write, the gEBI & .rows version is 11 characters shorter. Even `id("tblOne").rows` is still 8 characters smaller then `$('#tblOne > tbody > tr')`

Comment: @Raynos using QSA _to me_ is just more immediate. It would be _to me_ more natural use it, so it would be more faster to think and to write Ok? (Probably because I don't think to make an unnecessary optimization over a single selection)

Comment: I had code that was using JQuery to do simple text searching in tables.  With 6000+ rows it was noticeably laggy.  Changed it to use regular JS and it was 10 fold faster.

Comment: By using QSA.... your throwing away cross browser support and limiting your website to newer browsers only... The only sad part about web development is this sort of stuff....

Answer (score 22):

Use [immediate children selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) `>`:

```
$('#tblOne > tbody  > tr')
```

> Description: Selects all **direct child elements** specified by "child" of
>   elements specified by "parent".