# Script JS with For Loop over tables

Tags: javascript, html

I am a very beginner with Javascript and I want to write a script that modifies the style of (some) tables, at the end of the parsing of an html page.

I have a (hopefully) MWE of such script:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
<!--
    var Ri = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var Ca = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var nRi = Ri.length;
    var nCa = Ca.length;
    var nCo = nCa/nRi;
    for (var i = 0; i < nCo; i++)
    {
        Ca[i].style.backgroundColor="rgb(221,247,255)";
    }
    for (var i = nCo; i < nCa; i = i+nCo)
    {
        Ca[i].style.backgroundColor="rgb(221,247,255)";
    }
//-->
</script>
```

but, as you can easily verify, it would work *correctly* only if there's a single table in the html page.

The question is the following. Let us say there are **m** tables with the attribute `class="tabx"` in the html page. How can I edit the script so that it counts the **m** tables with the attribute `class="tabx"` in the page and, say for **j=1,...,m**, performs the loops

```
for (var i = 0; i < nCo; i++)
{
    Ca[i].style.backgroundColor="rgb(221,247,255)";
}
for (var i = nCo; i < nCa; i = i+nCo)
{
    Ca[i].style.backgroundColor="rgb(221,247,255)";
}
```

on each of such tables?

Thanks, I couldn't find this in particular on this network with keywords search, and not even in documentation in italian that's plentyful as well...and I know it would take 2 seconds using CSS instead...

Comment: did you take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431987/jquery-each-loop-in-table-row)?

Comment: do you have any restrictions to use jquery?

Comment: @Claudio Santos I would not like to use jQuery cause I was now concentrating on JS syntax. But the link in your first comment looks to be inherent. Honestly: give me 15 min to read it properly ;) Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you do it.

```
    var t1 = document.getElementsByClassName("tabx");

for(index = 0; index < t1.length; ++index)
{
        var Ri = t1[index].getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var Ca = t1[index].getElementsByTagName("td");
        var nRi = Ri.length;
        var nCa = Ca.length;
        var nCo = nCa / nRi;
        for (var i = 0; i < nCo; i++) {
            Ca[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(221,247,255)";
        }
        for (var i = nCo; i < nCa; i = i + nCo) {
            Ca[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgb(221,247,255)";
        }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a5F9b/1/

hope that help.